# jQuery - moving an element of a list item inside another element of the same item + do this for each item of my list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, move

I have a generated HTML menu that looks like this :

```
<ul class="principal-nav">
     <li><a href="#">Item 01</a> <span class="posts-amount">(12)</span></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 02</a> <span class="posts-amount">(7)</span></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 03</a> <span class="posts-amount">(25)</span></li>
</ul>
```

And I need it to look like this :

```
<ul class="principal-nav">
     <li><a href="#">Item 01 <span class="posts-amount">(12)</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 02 <span class="posts-amount">(7)</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 03 <span class="posts-amount">(25)</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried to manipulate the DOM but I'm a jQuery beginner and, so far, all I succeed in getting was this result :

```
<ul class="principal-nav">
     <li><a href="#">Item 01 <span class="posts-amount">(12)</span> <span class="posts-amount">(7)</span> <span class="posts-amount">(25)</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 02 <span class="posts-amount">(12)</span> <span class="posts-amount">(7)</span> <span class="posts-amount">(25)</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 03 <span class="posts-amount">(12)</span> <span class="posts-amount">(7)</span> <span class="posts-amount">(25)</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's my jQuery code :

```
$('.principal-nav li a').append(
     $('span.posts-amount').clone().end()
);
```

I think I can get something working using "each" but for some reason, I couldn't achieve it yet.
I've been looking at a whole lot of boards and tutorials, but couldn't find any answer to my question.

Thank you for helping me out !

Comment: This is a concept error. In you need to fix with jQuery a design problem, surely you can fix it before. Why do not generate HTML correctly. If you fix it at design, you won't need use jQuery later.

Comment: I fully agree with you. The problem is that I'm stuck with an old version of Wordpress. I don't want to edit a file that's outside of my theme directory. I tried to create a new menu (there's a nice functionnality aimed for that), but it crashed my blog. I don't have the time right now to re-do this blog from start as it is only a side project. That's why I go the jQuery way. But again, you're fully right : there's a better and cleaner way to do that ;)

Comment: Sometimes the best way is not the more efficent and is not the fast. I understand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RJzq7/

```
$('.principal-nav li a').each(function () {
  $(this).next().appendTo(this);
});
```

Comment: I already accepted your answer, but the board asked to wait 6 minutes for it to be validated. I'm all good with your code. Perfectly fits my needs. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Clone will create duplicate copy of elements. So use appendTo() instead.